# Use maven to "extend" existing jar file

Tags: maven

My project contains a couple of class which have to be integrated into an final jar file.

So my current "workflow" looks like:

```
mvn compile && jar uf contribution.jar -C target/classes .
```

I guess this could be done with the maven-jar plugin or through maven-assemblies but can't figure out how.

Comment: Simply call `mvn package` instead of `mvn compile`.

Comment: The "contribution.jar" is not an artifact which I created within my maven project. It's just a jar file which is part of another software release. Even with "mvn package" I'd have to run the "jar uf ..." stuff ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple - add the element `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to your `pom.xml` and invoke the following:

```
mvn package
```

See [Maven build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for more information. It really is a must-read if you're planning to use Maven for you project.

**Edit**

Thanks for the update, I know understand what you mean. There may be a better way to do this, but this is what I use:

Maven will automatically include this jar if you add it as a dependency in the usual way, i.e:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>contribution</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...        
</dependencies>
```

The question is how to ensure that maven can find the jar? If the jar were in the Maven Global repository it would find it automatically, so always check this first. If not, then you will have to **create your own repository to store custom jars**. This may not be the most clever way to do it, but it's how I do it. Note that this is **not** the same thing as the cache stored in the `.m2` folder.

Let's say we want to use c:\maven\repo as our local. To do this, first ensure the folder exists then add the following lines to your `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
        <url>file://c:\maven\repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Next, you will need to manually add the contribution jar to this repo. To do this execute the `mvn deploy:deploy-file` command and give it the appropriate values. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) for more information.

Now when build/compile/package your original project, it should include contribution.jar in the packaging as it is a dependency.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Adding the packaging jar is not needed, cause it's the default.

Comment: The question wasn't how to use maven for jar generation :(

Comment: Thx - after the edit the answer actually was what I was looking for.